# Unable to launch my android apps. “Shutting down VM” Error

Tags: java, android, exception, virtual-machine

I'm total newbie to java programming, my app worked flawleslly until now, I can't find cause of error. App shuts down when opening instantly(force close).  Thanks in advance!

Logcat:

```
09-02 01:07:15.932 15469-15469/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-02 01:07:15.959 15469-15469/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver-2/lib/arm
09-02 01:07:16.011 15469-15469/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver-2/lib/arm
09-02 01:07:16.046 15469-15469/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver W/Xposed: Package name for /data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/left/resources.ap_ had to be retrieved via parser
09-02 01:07:16.081 15469-15469/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver V/UUID: 52e2e4ec-0541-4e5e-b599-467ee6fec3aa
09-02 01:07:16.084 15469-15469/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-02 01:07:16.085 15469-15469/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver, PID: 15469
                                                                                   Theme: themes:{}
                                                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;
                                                                                       at com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver.MainActivity.requestPermission(MainActivity.java:606)
                                                                                       at com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:122)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7125)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5475)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                       at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.1.1_97e3b4268259621b3c54683f9e2f54c902b84549-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                       at com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver.MainActivity.requestPermission(MainActivity.java:606) 
                                                                                       at com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:122) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7125) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5475) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                       at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
                                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                            ... 16 more
                                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.1.1_97e3b4268259621b3c54683f9e2f54c902b84549-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.yusuf.bluetoothserver-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                                                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                ... 17 more
                                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
```

Code (ugly as hell, I know):

(I've removed import things, cause of body limit characters won't let me post)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


    static final int Permission_Req_Code = 1;
    Button pairBtn;
    Button discoverBtn;
    ToggleButton discoverToggle;
    boolean isRegistered;
    boolean btExitSetting;
    boolean inSettings;
    boolean serverListening;

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton receiveRadioBtn;
    RadioButton sendRadioBtn;

    EditText userInputField;
    String userInput = "";
    String clientMsg;
  //  Button receiveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.receiveBtn);





    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        Log.v("UUID",String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));

        /* ___ Setting Up Bluetooth ___ */
        // - Get the BluetoothAdapter -
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        ////BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        ////bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast noBT_toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Device does not support Bluetooth!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            noBT_toast.show();
        }

        // - Enable Bluetooth -
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
        }


        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        // * As of Marshmallow, permissions that are not considered "normal" (dangerous - may expose user data), must be granted by user at runtime.
        // This includes starting bluetooth discovery feature.

        // Request Location Permission (needed for Bluetooth) at RunTime:
        requestPermission();


        pairBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pairBtn);
        pairBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ___ Finding paired devices ___ //
                pairedDevices();
            }
        });

        discoverToggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.discoverToggle);
        discoverToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    discoverDevices();
                }
                else if (!isChecked) {
                    disableDiscovery();
                }
            }
        });


        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        receiveRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.receiveRadioBtn);
        sendRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sendRadioBtn);

      //  userInputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInputField);
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        View view = menu.findItem(R.id.action_connect).getActionView();
        Switch connect_switch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.connect_switch);
        connect_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                AcceptThread acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
                if (isChecked) {
                    Log.d("Switch", "Checked");
                        acceptThread.start();
                }
                else if (!isChecked) {
                    Log.d("Switch", "!Checked");
                    acceptThread.closeConnection();
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent settingIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(settingIntent);

            inSettings = true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_exit) {
            onStop();
            finish();
        }

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            btExitSetting = sharedPref.getBoolean("pref_key_exit_bluetooth", false);
            Log.v("Bundle", String.valueOf(btExitSetting));

            inSettings = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.w("onStop", "invoked!");

        disableDiscovery();

        if (btExitSetting && !inSettings) {
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.w("onDestroy", "invoked!");
    }


    /* ___ Finding paired devices ___ */
    private void pairedDevices() {
        // - Querying paired devices -
        final Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                arrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }


    // - Discovering devices -
    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.v("onReceive","Invoked");

            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                Log.v("BT Devices","Found");

                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                arrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.e("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            else {

                Log.v("BT Devices","!!!Found");

            }

            isRegistered = true;

        }
    };


    private void discoverDevices() {
        // - Enabling discoverability -
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        // * Add following actions to ensure the start of the BT dicovery mode.
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            Log.e("adapter","Not Null!");
        }

        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            Log.e("BTadapter","Discovering!");
        }
    }

    private void disableDiscovery() {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        if (isRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }


    /* ___ Accepting Client Connection. ___*/
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        ConnectedThread connectedThread;

        public AcceptThread() {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
            // because mmServerSocket is final
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
                String NAME = "BluetoothServer";
                UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("0ae3d869-470e-45d1-b147-a10882fc1bd2");
                tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);

                Log.e("Server", "Listening");

            }
            catch (IOException e) { }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                    Log.e("Connection","Accepted");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {

                    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
                    connectedThread.start();
                    cancel();

                }
            }
        }

        /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public void closeConnection() {
            if (connectedThread != null) {
                connectedThread.close();
            }
        }

    }


    /* Managing Connection */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        BufferedReader inputStream;
        PrintWriter outputStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                outputStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }




        public void run() {



            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.receiveRadioBtn);
            rb.setOnClickListener(new RadioButton.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)

                /*{ Synchro Sync = new Synchro();
                    Thread t = new Thread(Sync);
                    t.start();}*/
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                        read();

                        TextView clientMsgTxV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clientMsgTxV);
                        clientMsgTxV.setText(clientMsg);
                        Log.i("Server MSG", clientMsg);
                    }
                }
            });

            final ToggleButton receiveBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.receiveBtn);
            receiveBtn.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            if (mmInStream.available() > 0 ){
                                read();
                                TextView clientMsgTxV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clientMsgTxV);
                                clientMsgTxV.setText(clientMsg);
                                Log.i("Server MSG", clientMsg);
                            }
                            else SystemClock.sleep(100);
                        }
                        catch(IOException Io)
                        {
                            close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    }
            });
        }


        private void read() {
            try {

                if(inputStream.ready()) {
                    if ((clientMsg = inputStream.readLine()) != null || !("".equals(clientMsg))) {
                    } else {
                        clientMsg = "empty";
                    }


                    Log.i("Server MSG", clientMsg);
                    Log.v("InputStream", "Read");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void write() {
            // To ensure that the User Input is added to the output stream - add a conditional statement to check if userInput variable is not null.
            if (userInput != null) {
                Log.e("User Input", userInput);
                outputStream.println(userInput);
                Log.d("Output Stream", "Written to Client");
            }
        }

        /* Shutdown the connection */
        public void close() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }




    private void requestPermission() {
        // Here, this is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        Permission_Req_Code);

                // Permission_Req_Code is an app-defined int constant.
                // The callback method gets the result of the request.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Permission_Req_Code: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted - Do the BT-related task you need to do.

                } else {

                    // permission denied - Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.

                    String btPermissionDeniedStr = "Sorry, Bluetooth communication is not possible without granting location permission";
                    Toast.makeText(this,btPermissionDeniedStr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setReToText() {


        TextView clientMsgTxV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clientMsgTxV);
        clientMsgTxV.setText(clientMsg);
        Log.i("Server MSG", clientMsg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to that you're missing the support library. Can you post your build.gradle file for app module and project?